# Android toolbars and whether they are nullable

Tags: android-layout, kotlin

As seems to be typical for Android development, it doesn't work.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar)  Why doesn't this work? Type mismatch: inferred type is android.widget.Toolbar but androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar? was expected

        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
    }
}
```

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"    >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rwb.toolbarhide, PID: 3989
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.widget.Toolbar
        at com.rwb.toolbarhide.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is this something to do with `androidx` and different `Toolbar`s?
How can you tell if this is so?
What can be done to fix it?

What I wanted to know, however, was why the line commented out doesn't work.

How can we tell if `findViewById` is returning a `Toolbar` or a `Toolbar?` (in VisualStudio you would just hover the mouse, but not so in AndroidStudio -- it seems to be impossible).

So, if indeed we do have a `Toolbar` and not a `Toolbar?` then how can we pass it to `setSupportActionBar`?

(I want a `Toolbar` not a `Toolbar?` because it's a right nuisance having to `?` and `!!` all over the place.)

Comment: Which type of Toolbar used in imports section? I suppose it should be `import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`

Answer (score 0):

`import android.widget.Toolbar`. It would have been done by the intellisense if it wasn't there as standard because I have no idea what I'm doing. Did it guess the wrong one?

This seems to have pacified it:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```